# "The search engine appears to be down or failing to respond to the search query"

Tags: fusionauth

I've installed FusionAuth (awesome product) into a Docker Swarm cluster using the official `docker-compose.yml` file and everything seems to work brilliantly.

EXCEPT

Periodically, when a user goes to login they will be presented with the above error stating that the search engine is not available. If they try again immediately then everything works correctly! I would, obviously, prefer that they never saw the error.

Elasticsearch is definitely running and is responding to API calls correctly, and I can see the `fusionauth_user` index is present and populated with docs.

I guess my question is two fold:

1) What role does the ElasticSearch engine play in the FusionAuth ecosystem and can it be disabled?

2) Is there a configurable timeout somewhere that is causing the error message and, if so, where can change it?

I've search the docs for answers to the above but I can't seem to find anything :-(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the kind feedback.

> 1) What role does the ElasticSearch engine play in the FusionAuth ecosystem and can it be disabled?

Elasticsearch provides full text search of user data. Each time a user is created or updated the user is re-indexed. In this case during login, we are updating the search index with the last login instant.

This service is required and cannot be disabled. We have had clients request to make this service optional for embedded applications or small scale scenarios where Elasticsearch may not be required. While this is not currently in plan, it is possible we may revisit this option in the future.

> 2) Is there a configurable timeout somewhere that is causing the error message and, if so, where can change it?

Not currently.

Full disclosure, I am not a Docker or Docker Swarm expert at all - perhaps there are some nuances to Swarm and response time due to spin up and spin down of resources?

Do you see any exceptions in the log when a user sees this error on the login?

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar/the same problem.

We run the awesome FusionAuth in a cluster orchestrated by Docker Swarm.

A snippet of my docker-compose.yml for the sake of completenes (though I don't think it is relevant to the problem):

```
  fusionauth-database:
    image: postgres:12.9
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_USER=aPostgresUser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=aReallyGoodPassword
    networks:
      - fusionauth-data
    volumes:
      - fusionauth-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    
  fusionauth-search:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
    environment:
      - cluster.name=fusionauth
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    networks:
      - fusionauth-search
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1.5GB
    volumes:
      - fusionauth-search-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data


  fusionauth-app:
    image: fusionauth/fusionauth-app:latest
    depends_on:
      - fusionauth-database
      - fusionauth-search
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://fusionauth-database:5432/fusionauth
      - DATABASE_ROOT_USERNAME=aDbUserThatHasRootPermissions
      - DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD=theReallyGoodPasswordOfThatRootUser
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=aDbUser
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=theReallyGoodPasswordOfThatUser
      - FUSIONAUTH_APP_MEMORY=512M
      - FUSIONAUTH_APP_RUNTIME_MODE=production
      - FUSIONAUTH_APP_URL=http://fusionauth-app:9011
      - SEARCH_SERVERS=http://fusionauth-search:9200
      - SEARCH_TYPE=elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - fusionauth-app-config:/usr/local/fusionauth/config
    networks:
      - fusionauth-data
      - fusionauth-search

volumes:
  fusionauth-app-config:
  fusionauth-data:
  fusionauth-search-data:
  fusionauth-db-data:

networks:
  fusionauth-data:
  fusionauth-search:
```

FYI: we differentiate between the search and db traffic by using two separate networks (`fusionauth-data` and `fusionauth-search`).

Our app searches in the FusionAuth api for users on their fullname. It therefore uses this route:

```
/api/user/search?queryString=fullName:"Puk"
```

That works fine, but after a significant period of inactivity in my app (and therefore in FusionAuth as well) FusionAuth responds with:

```
{
  "fieldErrors":{},
  "generalErrors":[{
    "code":"[SearchEngineUnavailableException]",
    "message":"Your search engine appears to be down."
  }]
}
```

If my app does an identical request immediately following the first, the second request will succeed.

My guess is that the connection from the FusionAuth app to ElasticSearch is closed or timed out but FusionAuth is unaware of that until it uses the connection to run the search query. It will create a new connection but will throw an error on the first request.

I use this poor man's workaround to circumvent:

```
// Once in a while a 'cold' query to FA leads to a SearchEngineUnavailableException error.
if (fusionAuthsJsonResponse?.generalErrors
  && fusionAuthsJsonResponse?.generalErrors[0]
  && fusionAuthsJsonResponse?.generalErrors[0]?.code === '[SearchEngineUnavailableException]'
  ) {
  // Repeat the search request
}
```